# OpenMP nested loop with dynamic array assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, parallel-processing, openmp

Please forgive me if this is a stupid question but I failed to find any question similar.

I want to assign the value to a 3d dynamic array with OpenMP parallel on the first loop (in C++).

```
int i, j, k;
int ***data;
const int NEL = 100;
const int NINT = 2;
data = new int**[NEL];
for (i = 0; i < NEL; i++) {
    data[i] = new int*[NINT*NINT*NINT];
    for (j = 0; j < NINT*NINT*NINT; j++) {
        data[i][j] = new int[NINT*NINT*NINT];
    }
}
#pragma omp parallel for 
for (i = 0; i < NEL; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < NINT*NINT*NINT; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < NINT*NINT*NINT; k++) {
            data[i][j][k] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I only want to make the outermost loop (i) execute parallel with the nested loops (j and k) execute sequentially. But the compiler throws the access violation error every time.

If I change the dynamic array to a local array, it would work with no problem.

```
int i, j, k;    
const int NINT = 2;
const int NEL = 100;
int data[NEL][NINT*NINT*NINT][NINT*NINT*NINT];
#pragma omp parallel for 
for (i = 0; i < NEL; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < NINT*NINT*NINT; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < NINT*NINT*NINT; k++) {
            data[i][j][k] = 123;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with OpenMP function enabled. Is it because that the OpenMP version in VS 2015 is only 2.0? Or I'm not using the dynamic array with OpenMP correctly?

Comment: Regardless of the error, parallelizing at this tiny granularity would incur huge overheads, and at this size also horrible cache thrashing over false conflicts.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The value of NINT and NEL here are only for demonstration purpose. Thanks for the advice on the performance issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the loop variables within the parallel region, best do

```
 #pragma omp parallel for 
 for (int i = 0; i < NEL; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < NINT*NINT*NINT; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < NINT*NINT*NINT; k++) {
        data[i][j][k] = 1;
      }
    }
 }
```

else, the loop variables will be shared by default, potentially leading to out-of-bounds access to `data`

In general, it is preferable here to use a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int >  > > data;
```

And if you opt for performance, you want to use contigous memory

```
std::vector<int> data;
```

and then access `data` by building the index on the fly

```
data[k+pow(NINT,3)*j+pow(NINT,6)*i] = 1;
```

Best use a small indexing function here, to make access to data easier

```
int dataIndex(int i, int j, int k, int NINT){return k+pow(NINT,3)*j+pow(NINT,6)*i;}
```

and then access `data` as

```
data[dataIndex(i,j,k,NINT)]=1;
```

The compiler will inline the function most likely, such that there will be no extra cost for the function call.

Comment: Thanks Kai! That solved my problem! The performance improvement you mentioned makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the pramga into;

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(data) private(i,j,k)
```

However, to expand on my comment, you are parallelizing over a large number of threads, but giving each of them a tiny amount of work, which means the overhead in scheduling them would be very large compared to the actual benefit.

On top of that, 2*2*2*sizeof(int) may be smaller than a cacheline on most systems, meaning that 2 threads would likely try to write to the same line simultaneously, causing false conflicts and ping-ponging the line across caches.

Comment: Thanks, Leeor. This works for me. I do need to make i, j and k private.

Comment: Better to make i,j,k explicitly local as for(int i = 0; ...) .  I assume the default of the outer for index defaulting to private is present only to permit use of C89 under OpenMP.